# Sum numbers in textboxes to a single textbox without button

Tags: vb.net

Ok, I am looking for the code to sum numbers from multiple boxes (2 in this case) and automatically fill another box with the sum without clicking a button or anything.  I'm talking about displaying the sum in the third box while numbers are being inputted into the first two boxes.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to the TextBox [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) events, and update the third text box when the text in either of the first two changes.

Just make sure you handle invalid input carefully (ie: use `Int32.TryParse` instead of `Int32.Parse`), as exceptions will likely be raised as the text box values aren't numbers.

Comment: He can use a KeyPress event handler to filter out non-numeric characters from appearing in the control, too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538.aspx#Y0

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm pretty new to coding.  Can you give me an example?