# How do I sum numbers in multiple text boxes while simulatneously putting the sum of those boxes in a seperate box without a button

Tags: vb.net

How do I sum numbers in multiple text boxes while simulatneously putting the sum of those boxes in a seperate box without a button.  Ok, I am looking for the code to sum numbers from multiple boxes (2 in this case) and automatically fill another box with the sum without clicking a button or anything. I'm talking about displaying the sum in the third box while numbers are being inputted into the first two boxes. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum numbers in textboxes to a single textbox without button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910639/sum-numbers-in-textboxes-to-a-single-textbox-without-button)

Comment: I didn't realize you had already asked this question and received (and accepted) the same answer I gave you. Could you rephrase this question or clarify it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You need to add an event handler for the [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) event. Add the handler for the two text boxes where the addends are being placed and update the sum in the event handler. The link has an example of parsing the text into numbers and doing something with them. In your case you need to parse two text boxes, you can either share the handler and parse both boxes each time, or add a separate handler for each box and update a member variable in the event and update the sum from the member variables (add a method called `UpdateSum` or something like that that you call after updating the member variables).

I am a C++/C# programmer so my VB syntax may be slightly off

```
Private Sub txtMonT_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Handles txtMonT.TextChanged
    Dim number1 As Double
    Dim number2 As Double

    If Double.TryParse(txtMon1.Text, number1)
        And Double.TryParse(txtMon2.Text, number2) Then
        txtMonResult.Text = (number1 + number2).ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit - Example of UpdateSum method
Note: `_addend1` and `_addend2` are assumed to be `Private` members of the class containing `UpdateSum` and that they are of type `Double` and have been set in the event handlers for the two text boxes. It is assumed that `UpdateSum` is being called from those handlers.

```
Private Sub UpdateSum()
    Dim result As Double
    result = _addend1 + _addend2
    txtMonResult.Text = result.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: haha You're speaking waayyy beyond me.  Sorry, I am a beginner.  Can you give me some example code?

Comment: @Shinobi1173 - There is an example at the provided link. Just click the VB tab to see the example in VB code.

Comment: Haha Still speak beyond me.  Sorry to be such a noob

Comment: this is what I have:     
        Try
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMon1.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMon2.Text) Then
                MsgBox(Title:="Error", Prompt:="Enter a number.")
            End If
            If Not IsNumeric(txtMon1.Text) OrElse Not IsNumeric(txtMon2.Text) Then
                MsgBox(Title:="Error", Prompt:="Enter a number.")
            End If
        Catch
            txtMonT.Text = CStr(CDbl(txtMon1.Text) + CDbl(txtMon2.Text))
        End Try

Comment: @Shinobi1173 - I can't really help you beyond that. You should google and find some links/blogs/tutorials of event handling in a VB.Net forms application.

Comment: This is what I have:    Private Sub txtMonT_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtMonT.TextChanged
        Dim number As Double
        If Double.TryParse(txtMonT.Text, number) Then
            ' Set your member variable for addend1
            UpdateSum(txtMon1.Text + txtMon2.Text)
        End If

    End Sub

Comment: I am getting an error for updatesum.  Is it pretty much saying that updatesum is not declared.  Is there another command we can use?

Comment: @Shinobi1173 - If you are following the stub I wrote then you have to write `UpdateSum` and you need to add a member variable (or member field) to store the value of `addend1`. I don't know what your text box is called, I just named the handler for one called `addend1`. I have answered your basic question, but SO is not a site to have your program written for you, it is designed to answer specific questions.

Comment: I thought this was pretty specific

Comment: Isnt this site here to get help from people who know what they are doing and not just to get a high rep so you look cool?

Comment: @Shinobi1173 - and I have answered pretty specifically. You asked if you could update a sum based on text boxes changing. I told you that you can, provided a link to the handler you would need and added a quick sample of it. If you can't add the handler, add a method, add a member field I can't help you.

Comment: but I do appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: I do know how to add that stuff, I just do not know the format.  Also, keep in mind that UpdateSum doesnt work.

Comment: @Shinobi1173 - updated the sample again. `UpdateSum` would work if you wrote it. It is not built in to the framework. What you needed to do for `UpdateSum` is make it a member method (`Sub`) of the form class, then add member fields for `addend1` and `addend2`. In `UpdateSum` you would then add them together and set the result text box.